# Warning and Runtime Error in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

i am geting runtime error when i run my asp.net project. the application also gives me warning in these line

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"   
    AutoEventWireup="true"   
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"   
    Inherits="v_r_Default"       
    EnableTheming="false"   
    StylesheetTheme=""   
    Theme=""   
 %>
```

Warning :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing' or one of its
>   dependencies.    This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and    cannot be loaded.

and also when i run the application then it gives me error like that.

plz help me...it is an online website... www.allcontact.com

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the version of the project / solution matches the version of the dlls you are using with the project.

Also check for valid references to all the libraries or binaries you are using in your project / solution.

Comment: thanx sir...as you knw system.drawing.dll is buil.in in .net (my project using .net 3.5). can you suggest me download link to download this dll and add it to my project because it is a very big site and this dll are used in alot of places????

Comment: This file should be already there in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` folder of your system (for .Net v3.5). If not you may like to repair your installation of .Net Assembly.